# Cmd window dissappear right after running php -v command

Tags: php, windows, cmd

When I was trying to run

php -v

on a cmd window, a new window appears and disappears almost immediately which make me cannot read any of the output text. This happened with any other php script that I tried to run through cmd. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my system?

I use Wamp server 2.5, php version 5.5.12, windows 7 sp1. I have already put the path to my php folder to PATH variable.

Comment: Where are you getting PHP from? Wampserver2? Xampserver? etc. What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: Well, I use WAMP 2.5, my Windows version is Windows 7 sp1. I've already include the link to my PHP folder to the PATH variable.

Comment: And the PATH points to `c:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.Y.Z`?

Comment: Any possibility you have another php.exe in your PATH before the one in the wamp directory?

Comment: I have a similar setup and when I run `\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php -v` I get back the version information in the same window without problems. Why don't you try specifying the exact path like that?

Comment: As I have checked, the path is the same and there is no other php.exe in my PATH.

Comment: When I tried to run \wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php -v , it happened the same as before.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue.

Comment: Well, I had to reinstall my Windows OS. Saved a lot of time on finding that damned bug.